# Does NPOCO Append(arg1, arg2) prevents SQL injection?

Tags: c#, npoco

It is not clear to me by looking at the source code if the method 
`public Sql Append(string sql, params object[] args)` in the [NPOCO](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/blob/master/src/NPoco/Sql.cs) library prevents SQL injection.

For simplicity(my query is more complex than this), given the following example, with `filter` being a param passed by the client:

```
var sql = new Sql();
sql.Append("SELECT * FROM Request WHERE [Company] LIKE @0", $"%{filter}%");
```

Is this code prone to SQL injection?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I ask as I'm facing a similar predicament.

Comment: Yes it does. Just by inspecting the queries, you'll be able to see that strings are not being appended.

Answer (score 0):

SqlBuilsder.AddTemplate code takes in this exact same kind of sql string.
I then followed through the Fetch code in NPoco.  In the end you end up with a parameterized query such as
`DECLARE @0 Int = '4'
DECLARE @1 NVarChar = '%bad sql%' OR 1=1 --%'

SELECT BLAH WHERE Something = @0 AND SomethingElse = @1`

Which will break on the sql injection and thus returns NULL.

A good way to test your fears is to download NPOCO and just add it to your solution...refer to it rather than a nuget and step through the code to see the  final result.